# Data in one cell separated by semicolon

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, powerquery

I have the data like this:

[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yaku1.png)

What I need to do is based on the data in column B to count depending on the product code their number for a given index. The problem for me is the semicolons that separate the values.

I tried many solutions like formulas or PowerQuery. Unfortunately, I was not able to create anything sensible. Therefore I ask for help. The solution could be in Formulas, PQ or even VBA is necessary.

Comment: Can you add some of the formulas you tried and failed? It's not that complicated with formulas tbh.

Comment: Please update your question with an example of your desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because it's where my mind is, you can use `FILTERXML`.

```
=IFERROR(LEN(
CONCAT(FILTER(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($B2,";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),
FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($B2,";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")=C$1)))/LEN(C$1),"")
```

[image]

Note I specifically avoided the more logical `COUTNIF` since it doesn't seem to work on dynamic arrays. Instead I use the strategy shown in the formula: concatenate the cells in the dynamic array which are the same as the header, and then divide the length of the resultant string by the length of the header.

Answer (score 0):

Count instances by index

[image]

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Source,null,"[null]",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"code of product"}),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Replaced Value", "code of product", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"code of product.1", "code of product.2", "code of product.3"}),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter", {"index"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Custom", each 1),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Added Custom", List.Distinct(#"Added Custom"[Value]), "Value", "Custom", List.Sum)
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```